# knockoutjs: prevent event bubbling for elements with no handler

Tags: events, event-handling, knockout.js, event-bubbling

It seems like the binding `<event>Bubble: false` only works when there's [a defined event handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) (*see Note 4*) for `<event>`.

Here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stvnmntjy/stjFM/).

For elements having native handlers for certain events (e.g. click: `<textarea>`, `<a>`, `<select>`, etc.), where the native handler suffices, I would expect setting the binding, e.g., `clickBubble: false` on them, without having to bind a "bogus" handler, to work.

I guess my question is, is there another knockout way to achieve this without extra bindings?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `Bubble` handlers are not actual binding handlers and are used as options in the `event` binding (`click` binding calls `event` binding).  So, they do not run on their own.

So, you can add a "bogus" no-op handler and use `clickBubble` or you could certainly choose to create a custom binding to do this for you.

Maybe something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.preventBubble = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var eventName = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, eventName, function(event) {
           event.cancelBubble = true;
           if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
           }                
        });
    }        
};
```

And then just put:

```
<input data-bind="preventBubble: 'click'" />
```

You could also enhance it further to accept an array of events, if necessary.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WcXwZ/

Comment: Thanks, RP. I think the custom binding and use of the `utils` library, as per your fiddle, is far more attractive for multi-ViewModel apps and reusable than shimming bogus handlers on each VM class. I've +1ed your answer and am only giving the question a day or so to saute, to be fair, for other solutions. I won't forget to select the most elegant/useful, honest-engine.