# KnockoutJS: Checkbox Inside Click-Bound Anchor-Tag not Selectable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events, event-bubbling, knockout-3.0

I am trying to bind `checked` on a checkbox input which resides inside an anchor tag which, itself, is `click` bound.

Whilst I am aware that this may not be entirely valid (interactive content may not be descendant of anchor-tags), I would still like to get it to work as intended - even if just to understand it.

Currently, only the outside `click` event is handled and the click never arrives at my checkbox.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fzmppu93/2/

Having had a look through the KnockoutJS documentation, I tried `clickBubble: true` on the anchor-tag's `click` binding - to no avail.

The use case, if you're interested, is an unordered list containing links - each of these "links" contains information on a TV show: title, actors, image, synopsis. The show is selectable, but there are also 'quick-actions' to mark it as seen, star it, and so forth.

Is there another way of making a checkbox work inside an anchor-tag?

Comment: let me ask you a question here why you want to include check-box inside `anchor`  tag you can keep it out to make everything work normal . FYI @GoodQuestion/Answer .check here http://jsfiddle.net/fzmppu93/4/

Comment: The example was an over-simplification of rather convoluted mark-up/styling which I "inherited" and cannot currently change for reasons of templating/styling/continuity. Having a fair grasp of the HTML5 spec. I'm aware of what it *should* look like and am working with a view on changing it - but I'm bound right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [knockoutjs: prevent event bubbling for elements with no handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942279/knockoutjs-prevent-event-bubbling-for-elements-with-no-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a custom binding handler that is similar to "clickBubble", however mines allows to you to prevent the propagation of any event.

Here is the binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.preventBubble = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var eventName = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var arr = eventName;
            if (!eventName.pop) {
                arr = [arr];
            }
            for (var p in arr) {
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, arr[p], function (event) {
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                    if (event.stopPropagation) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

And here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzmppu93/3/) of your example.

Comment: Thank you very much - this bindingHandler is really useful and a very nice and elegant solution!